# Asp.Net MVC 5 - The type 'bool' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am displaying announcements in my home page. While getting announcements from database I am checking whether they are Active or not. If not I am not displaying on homepage but keeping them at database. When I try to set an announcement active to inactive I am getting this error before I debug the program.

```
  Error 5   The type 'bool' must be a reference type in order to use it as
  parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext
  .Entry<TEntity>(TEntity)'
```

This is my code

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Message,Title,Active")] Duyuru duyuru)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(duyuru.Title).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(duyuru.Message).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(duyuru.Active).State = EntityState.Modified; // I get the error at this line
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(duyuru);
        }
```

This is my model

```
public class Duyuru
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also if I do it this way

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Message,Title,Active")] Duyuru duyuru)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            duyuru.UploadDate = db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID).UploadDate;
            db.Entry(duyuru).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(duyuru);
    }
```

I get this error

```
 Attaching an entity of type '...Models.Duyuru' failed because another entity
 of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when
 using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or
 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may
 be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
 values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
 the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as       appropriate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to do this

```
db.Entry(duyuru).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Then all properties will be updated based on the key.

## update

instead of this

```
duyuru.UploadDate = db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID).UploadDate;
db.Entry(duyuru).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

you might want to do this

```
var duyuruDb = db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID);
duyuruDb.Message = duyuru.Message;
duyuruDb.Title= duyuru.Title;
duyuruDb.Active = duyuru.Active;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I get another error if I do it that way, since I don't want to update UploadDate. Also it works fine with other properties like duyuru.Title or duyuru.Message but it gives an error at duyuru.Active. I updated my question you can see the error

Comment: @CanTunç No, it doesn't work fine with other properties, it will merely fail at run-time rather than compile-time.

Comment: @CanTunç, [Entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) expects to accept the entity, not per property, also `it works fine with other properties like duyuru.Title` doesn't mean that the entity is updated to the database, if you're working on detached object with special rule like, `UploadDate` don't want to be updated, then you need to retrieve the object first or somehow preserve the original value of `UploadDate` from being updated in the UI

Comment: Yup I confirm, even though it's okay in the compile time, runtime will throw error if you pass an object that is not part of the context, something like `The entity type String is not part of the model for the current context.`

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you're meant to call the [`Entry` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696578%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). You're supposed to pass the entity object to it, not one of its properties. Since Entity Framework requires those entity objects to be classes, it happens to fail at compile time if the properties you're passing are value types.

`db.Entry(duyuru)` is a valid way to call the `Entry` method.

To address your comments:

> ```
>  duyuru.UploadDate = db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID).UploadDate;
>  db.Entry(duyuru).State = EntityState.Modified;
> ```

This fails because `db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID)` returns an entity that is attached to `db`. `duyuru` cannot then be attached to the same `db` context.

You could directly update the returned entity:

```
var entity = db.Duyuru.Find(duyuru.ID);
entity.Title = duyuru.Title;
// same for other properties
db.SaveChanges();
```

It is possible to use your original approach, but setting `State` to `EntityState.Modified` always marks all properties as modified. You may then retrieve the property entry (`var entry = db.Entry(duyuru);` and then access `entry.Property(propertyName)`) and set [`DbPropertyEntry.IsModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyentry.ismodified%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to `false` to specify that `UploadDate` is *not* modified. Or you may first attach your entity as unchanged, and explicitly set the properties to modified that you want to save.

Comment: I get another error if I do it that way, since I don't want to update UploadDate. Also it works fine with other properties like duyuru.Title or duyuru.Message but it gives an error at duyuru.Active. I updated my question you can see the error

Answer (score 0):

I will Partial update like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Duyuru duyuru)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
                db.Duyuru.Attach(duyuru); 
                db.Entry(duyuru).Property("Message").IsModified = true;
                db.SaveChanges();
         }

}
```